# c++ matrix template library need for neural networks computations

Tags: c++, matrix, neural-network

hi i'm implementing some neural network algorithms and i'll be needing a matrix library, I've looked and found that there are ones like ( boost::ublas ) , (blitz++), TNT... I need experts opinion which one is suitable for (simple , easy coding, high performance maybe )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent some reason to do otherwise, I'd probably go with boost::ublas. To be honest, I doubt that most of the code in *any* of them is going to contribute a lot toward a neural network, so it probably won't make a huge difference which one you choose. They'll all just be acting as simple containers.

Comment: [Eigen's](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) probably the best choice for a CPU BLAS library. The library uses expression templates, automatically uses SIMD instructions specific to your platform, and even multithreads certain algorithms using OpenMP. Depending on your network configuration and choice of optimization algorithm, there is a strong possibility that the code may use numerical linear algebra. Even elementwise operations are accelerated by Eigen.